# Insert Update trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert, sql-update

I want to write a trigger that

1. Inserts only updated/inserted records from a table eg. Address to another table let's say Address_trigger.
2. If a record is updated multiple times only the latest change is to be available in Address_trigger i.e replace the latest record with the current one.

The following code does the first part. But how to get the updates only?

```
CREATE or ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgUpdate]
  ON  [dbo].[Address]
  AFTER UPDATE,INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON; 
Insert into [Address_trigger] Select * from Inserted
END
```

Comment: After update trigger has data in the tables inserted and deleted, so you need something select i.* from inserted as i join deleted as d on i.id=d.id

Comment: Should the relationship perhaps be the other way around and `address_trigger` declared as a [Temporal table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)? Prefer built-in solutions over writing triggers, generally.

Answer (score 0):

use insert & update trigger, two triggers,

```sql
select 1 as ID, 'C-1' as C1
into [Address];

select *
into Address_trigger
from [Address]
where 1=0;
go;

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAddressInsert]
   ON [Address]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
Insert into [Address_trigger] 
Select * from Inserted;
END;
go;

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAddressUpdate]
   ON [Address]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

update t1
set C1 = t2.C1
from [Address_trigger] t1 inner join Inserted t2
on t1.ID = t2.ID;

END;
go;

insert into [Address](ID, C1) Values(2, 'c-2');
select * from [Address_trigger];
insert into [Address](ID, C1) Values(3, 'c-3');
select * from [Address_trigger];
update [Address] Set C1 = 'C-U' where ID = 3;
select * from [Address_trigger];
update [Address] Set C1 = 'C-x' where ID = 3;
select * from [Address_trigger];
```